# Getting <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x1069ce0d0> instead of values

Tags: django

I want to write all model fields to a text file but I am getting:How can I fix this?
I am making a patient registration form and after registration I want to see all the model fields in the text file. The code works, I am getting a text file but instead of the expected value I am seeing a deferredattribute. Where is my fault?

This is my model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    
    soru1 = models.CharField(verbose_name='Ad Soyad',max_length=10000, default="")
    soru2 = models.CharField(verbose_name='Tarih', max_length=10000, default="")
    soru3 = models.CharField(verbose_name='Doğum Tarihi', max_length=10000, default="")
    soru4 = models.CharField(verbose_name='Doğum Yeri', max_length=10000, default="")
    soru5 = models.CharField(verbose_name='Medeni Hali', max_length=10000, default="")
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.files import File



#Dosya Kaydetme

def writetofile(request):
    f = open('/Users/emr/Desktop/ngsaglik/homeo/patient/templates/kayitlar/test.txt', 'w')
    textfile = File(f)

    kayitlar = Post.objects.all()
    lines = []
    for kayit in kayitlar:
        lines.append(f'{Post.soru1}')

    textfile.write(str(lines))
    textfile.close
    f.close
    return HttpResponse()
```

And here is the result:

```
['<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x1069ce0d0>', '<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x1069ce0d0>']
```

Comment: You append the formatting of `Post.soru1` which is the model field, do you mean to format `kayit.soru1` instead?

Comment: Thanks bro :)))) you solved my problem very quickly. When i change the kayit, it works. :)

Comment: I wanna flag your answer as a solution, how can i make this. I can only make upvote.

Comment: @Prusa it's because it's a comment, and only answers can be flagged as correct. I added same thing as an answer with some explanation so we can close this subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change `Post.soru1` to `kayit.soru1`. It is because `Post` is call to the class, not instance you want to get in this case, that's why it shows only the model field instead of an instance's value.

`kayitlar = Post.objects.all()` here you assigned the all existing instances of `Post` model to variable `kayitlar`. Now you can forget about `Post` and process further the `kayitlar` variable with all objects.